# Unable to copy timestamp values filled with "N/A" to RedShift

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I have a DataFrame where I replaced some missing field values with "N/A" like `.na.fill("N/A", naColumns)`. However when the data is getting copied from S3 to RedShift I'm getting the Error: `Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]`

I understand that probably it's not the best idea to fill timestamp fields with string values. However if I'm not replacing the null values in a DataFrame I'm getting an error about a Delimiter not found when copying to RedShift. Which most likely indicates missing columns.

By the way the fields are not a part of a primary key and are `nullable`.

What would be the most appropriate way to fill null values of `timestamp` fields on the side of a DataFrame?

Comment: Please post your code for the write from Spark. Also, you should try filling with empty string. I think that will result in a null in the field on the copy into Redshift.

Comment: Can you use `Option[Timestamp]` type for representing timestamps? Then you would be able to pass `None` instead of `"N/A"`.

Comment: Did you check your `stl_load_errors` table? It will give you more info related to the error

Comment: If your target column data type is _timestamp_ then your only options are to supply either a valid timestamp value or NULL. If you want to store values like "N/A" or "None" then the target column will need to be of data type _varchar_.

Comment: @mdem7 yes I've checked `stl_load_errors` table. That's where I discovered the error `Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]`

Comment: @DemetriKots passing an empty string to fill null values in the _timestamp_ target column worked

Comment: @samba I will post as an answer below in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You should try filling with empty string. That will result in a null in the field on the copy into Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your nulls with an empty string: `''` and it will look like two consecutive commas in your line: `value1,value2,,value3` and will result with a `null` in timestamp column